# Pratical solving a least square problem - How to find the best fit?

Tags: optimization, curves, least-squares

I want to curve fit the straight line equation:

$$ y = kx + m$$

Where $k$ is the slope and $x$ is the variable and $m$ is where it cuts onto the y-axis.

So assume that we have a plot who looks like this:

[image]'

Code:

```
R = 1:50;
Y = R.*rand(1, 50);
plot(Y);
```

And I want to find the best fit by minimizing this cost function:

$$V(k,m) = \sum(Y - \hat{Y})^2 = \sum(Y-(kx + m))^2$$

So how can I find my best $k$ and best $m$ which minimize the cost function $V(k,m)$ ?

I want to solve this with a for-loop.

Comment: The math behind this kind of problem [is well understood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29). Are you stuck on the math somewhere, or the implementation? If it's the implementation, then this may not be the best SE site for your question.

Comment: @John I stuck on the implementation. Yes, it's the best SE site for my question.

Comment: @John And the math behind.

Comment: Look up linear regression. This is well described elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. I can't believe that all mathematics about linear regression was so difficult and hard explained, and my answer is the easiest one and does the job!

The estimated line of best fit

[image]

The line is about

$$y = 0.25x + 0.4$$

The cost function

[image]

The code:

```
%% Random values
R = 0.5:0.5:50;
Y = R.*rand(1, length(R));
figure(1)
plot(Y);


% Set up vectors
V = zeros(1, length(R)*length(R)); % Cost function vector
x = linspace(0, 100, length(R)); % x-axis vector
N = linspace(0, 0.6, length(R)); % Values for k and m

L = 0; % Initial
Vlast = 1e+6; % Initial
for i = 1:length(R)
  for j = 1:length(R)

    % Compute the estimated Y
    Yh = N(i).*x + N(j); % N(i) = k and N(j) = m

    % Count
    L = L + 1;

    % Compute the cost function
    V(L) = sum(Y - Yh).^2;

    % Check if the last cost value was higher
    if V(L) < Vlast
      Vlast = V(L); % Over write
      k = N(i); % Remeber
      m = N(j); % Remeber
    end

  end
end

% Plot the cost function 
figure(2)
plot(1:length(V), V)

% Plot the estimated line
figure(1)
hold on
plot(x, k.*x + m)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.